# Why does a URL containing '/' after a '$' return a Page Not Found Error (404)

Tags: django, url-routing

I'm having an issue with Django URL patterns.

When I add a '/' to the end of the index URL, the page returns a 404 error (Page Not Found) and if I remove the '/' from the end of the URL then the page works fine.

The issue is not reproducible with the URL for the admin page, can someone explain what's going on?

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$/',index),
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$`: Represents [**end**](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html) of string, so, there's no posibility for a char *living* after it.

> Matches the end of the string or just before the newline at the end of
>   the string

`^` matches the start of the string so, `^$` in root `urls.py` means to Django: *I don't want anything in my URL except the domain / base name* then Django will route the request to your index page.

Answer (score 2):

**url** method of `django.conf.urls` package accept regex as first parameter

`$` represent **end** of string in regular expression hence any char after that will not be considered to match url string.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood , in django urls:

'$' : End of the string, this is use in regex

'^' : It is also use in regular expression is matching starting of url

Answer (score -1):

no characters after **$** will be considered in the url pattern
hence change this to :

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^/$',index),
]
```